# Why MouseMotionListener's mouseMoved method generates event when component is set to visible?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have added `MouseMotionListener` to Component, about 5 parents above. When I set main `JWindow` `setVisible(true);`, then immediately `mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)` method generates one event. After that everything works fine. Could it be some bug?

Some solution is possible:

```
public class SomeClass extends Component{

   private int mouseMoveCount;

   public SomeClass(){

   addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

                    if (mouseMoveCount > 1) {
                        //Do something
                        mouseMoveCount = 0;
                    }
                    mouseMoveCount++;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

`jWindow.setVisible(true);` is done after `validate();` and `pack();`. Mouse, of course sits in place, I do not touch it :) But it still generates one event..

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the code. :)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. In general, you should add listeners to components after they render.

Comment: I found some solution, but I don't like it.

Comment: A quick and dirty hack would be to add a "boolean init = false" to the listener, and the first time mouseMoved is called (ie. when init is false), do nothing other than set "init" to true.

Comment: @Kon: _"you should add listeners to components after they render"_ I've never heard this before (or seen it in any demo code). Do you have a reference?

Comment: Please provide **SSCCE** [http://sscce.org/].  Very likely that while doing it you'll find the source of your problem.

Comment: @PM77-1 : Please enclose the `String literal` inside square brackets and add the link inside the parenthesis, like `[String literal](address goes here)` for the link to work. Here [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the reason - before setting to visible, I was dispatching `MouseEvent` (`MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED`) to `Component` `MouseListener` - it was a mistake. But interesting to know, that dispatching this event also triggered `mouseMoved`.